# How to know that horizontal collectionView section did end decelerating?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, uikit

I have a vertically scrolling collectionView where sections are scroll horizontally.
How to know that section did end decelerating? If I use

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        
    }
```

delegate just says me about vertical scrolling.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask]. We need a bit more information about how you've set up your *"vertically scrolling collectionView where sections are scroll horizontally"*.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Compositional Layout, you can achieve this kind of horizontal scroll logic via [visibleItemsInvalidationHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nscollectionlayoutsection/3199096-visibleitemsinvalidationhandler) inside [NSCollectionLayoutSection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nscollectionlayoutsection).

Like here:

```
sectionLayout.visibleItemsInvalidationHandler = { [weak self] items, contentOffset, environment in
        // Here you can add some code to handle some kind of logic using contentOffset
    }
```